# Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 12, column: 2, Trailing comma not allowed

Tags: json, google-chrome-theme

I'm trying to create my own Google Chrome theme.

> Manifest is not valid JSON.  Line: 12, column: 2, Trailing comma not
>   allowed.

Can anyone tell me the solution to this error?

```
{
  "version": "2.6",
  "manifest_version": "2",
  "name": "theme",
  "theme": {
    "images": {
      "theme_frame": "images_endcard01",
      "theme_frame_overlay": "images_endcard01",
      "theme_toolbar": "images_endcard01",
      "theme_ntp_background": "images_endcard01",
      "theme_ntp_attribution": "images_bg_mayoi"
    },
    "colors": {
      "frame": [71, 105, 91],
      "toolbar": [207, 221, 192],
      "ntp_text": [20, 40, 0],
      "ntp_link": [36, 70, 0],
      "ntp_section": [207, 221, 192],
      "button_background": [255, 255, 255]
    },
    "tints": {
      "buttons": [0.33, 0.5, 0.47]
    },
    "properties": {
      "ntp_background_alignment": "bottom"
    }
  }
}
```